# IE7 Absolute element appearing behind relative one

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I know there is the bug where absolute elements appear above relative ones. However I am getting the reverse of this issue.

The z-index on the "bottom" element is 1 and has a position:relative assigned. The top element has absolute positioning and a z-index of 99.

This works fine in Firefox, Webkit based browsers and IE8. Any ideas about why this could be happening?

Comment: This should be fine - post some code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In Internet Explorer positioned
>   elements generate a new stacking
>   context, starting with a z-index value
>   of 0. Therefore z-index doesn't work
>   correctly.

See

[Bug Report: Explorer z-index bug](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2006/01/Explorer_z_index_bug.html)

and

[Squish the Internet Explorer Z-Index Bug](http://www.brenelz.com/blog/2009/02/03/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/)

Comment: Giving the parent element a higher z-index fix it. Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
var zIndexNumber = 1000;
$('div').each(function() {
    $(this).css('zIndex', zIndexNumber);
    zIndexNumber -= 10;
});
```

});

Use the above if already using jQuery. Details here: http://www.vancelucas.com/blog/fixing-ie7-z-index-issues-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

I've found a helpful [resource](http://alex.leonard.ie/2013/01/27/ie-bug-text-ignores-z-index-of-higher-elements/) to address this:

Long story short, if your absolutely placed element is empty, IE doesn't like to place it in front of other elements (eg. relatively placed text). You can use a 1x1 transparent gif to overcome this, eg. by setting a style like the following on your absolutely placed element.

```
 .mask {
   background: transparent url('/images/clear.gif') repeat 0 0;
 }
```