# CSS positioned image not visible in Internet Explorer / IE z-index not fixing

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am working on a timeline where when a section of the timeline is complete, the background will be composed of a green image and the foreground will have an actual image element of a check mark.  This is how it looks (**correct**) in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari:

[image]

This is how it looks (**incorrect**) in IE 7 and 8 (maybe 9, haven't tested that yet):
[image]:

I am working with relative and absolute positioning.  I've tried about everything i can think of regarding z-index and other techniques.  I've even found an [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524987/ie7-absolute-element-appearing-behind-relative-one) on here that had a potential solution (make z-index of img element smaller than background's z-index) but that didn't work.

Anyways, please help!

Here's my (simplified) CSS:

```
    .timeline-container {
        width: 820px;
        height: 50px;
    }        
    .timeline-step {
        width: 164px;
        height: 22px;
        float: left;
        background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/amRJt.png) -10px 0px no-repeat;
    }                
    .complete {
        background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgSG6.png!) -10px 0px no-repeat;
        position: relative;
    }
    .complete img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        right: 50%;
    }                
    .timeline-divider {
        background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJw3e.png);
        height: 30px;
        width: 1px;
        float: right;
    }        
    .timeline-label {
        color: #C5C5C%;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Here's my (simplified) HTML:

```
<div class="timeline-container">
    <div class="timeline-step complete">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS83c.png" alt="complete" />
        <div class="timeline-divider">
        </div>
        <span class="timeline-label">Confirm Eligibility</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Any thoughts on how to get that checkbox to show up in front of the green "complete" section of the timeline?**  Thanks!

It looks to be working in JFiddle, but when taken out and used directly in IE, it fails...

Here is the JFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SY9q5/

Comment: Is your simplified code very different from your actual code? I tried this in IE 8 (w/ and w/o compatibility mode) using jsFiddle and it actually looks correct: http://jsfiddle.net/3mtXJ/

Comment: It works in jsfiddle, but when taken out of that and viewed directly in an IE browser, the check marks are not visible.  http://jsfiddle.net/SY9q5/

Answer (score 0):

Add a
position: relative;
z-index:0;
to .timeline-container

The parent tag and then assign a z index to your image of > 0

http://jsfiddle.net/5wsbC/

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work.  Your solution does get the check image in front, but pushes the divider and spacer down.  Also, the check mark is not centered. It moves the checkmark out of position in all four browsers.

Comment: It looks like you modified; let me try again.

Comment: Yeah i did sorry man! I noticed complete in the ALT read it as Class... I need more coffee, lol

Comment: It works in jsfiddle, but when taken out of that and viewed directly in an IE browser, the check marks are not visible.  http://jsfiddle.net/SY9q5/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using position absolute that could be the cause

Try

```
.complete img {

    padding-top:5px;
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    z-index:10;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BTxP6/1

Comment: It pushes the label and separator down.

Comment: Fair point this will do what you want http://jsfiddle.net/BTxP6/2/ however i would suggest changing your markup

Answer (score 0):

It is actually your `.timeline-divider` that is causing the issue, not an interaction with the container div `.complete`. Are you able to change the markup? If so you should be able to fix your problem simply by wrapping the lower two elements in another div:

```
<div class="timeline-step complete">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS83c.png" alt="complete" />
    <div>
        <div class="timeline-divider">
        </div>
        <span class="timeline-label">Complete Application</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Other possible fixes would be to add an empty div above `.timeline-divider` or to move the img below the two floats and make it `clear: both;`. Admittedly none of these solutions are particularly ideal but they will work.

It's also worth noting that this is actually a [rather well-documented bug](http://www.sitepoint.com/fix-disappearing-absolute-position-element-ie/).