# Absolute overlay div element doesn't cover relatively positioned elements

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

In IE7 browser, I just meet one issue about position.
I made a demo page to test the position conditions of relative and absolute.
There are the related codes below:

[CSS]

```
.rela{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background:#EEE;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    position:relative;
}
.abs{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    background:#333;
    left:20px;
    top:80px;
    z-index:10;
}
```

[HTML]

```
<div class="rela"><div class="abs"></div></div>
<div class="rela"><div class="abs"></div></div>
<div class="rela"><div class="abs"></div></div>
<div class="rela"><div class="abs"></div></div>
```

Now, the problem is, in IE7 browser, the "abs" element is covered by the next "rela" element, but it displays well in other browsers like Firefox, chrome, IE8.
I know somebody said that we can add a more higher z-index to the parent "rela" element, but for the codes above, the issue can't be fixed in this condition, coz there are more than two rela elements and all of them have the abs element.

I have no idea about how to fix it now. Also, if someone could kindly provide a official explanation about this "bug", it will be so good.

[image]

Comment: Ah... IE. Microsoft MVPs in action.

Comment: add to .rela `display:table;` might work. untested

Comment: sorry, (only) adding `display:table;` to `.rela` doesn't work

Comment: `display:table` doesn't work. Also it will break the correct layout for other browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524987/ie7-absolute-element-appearing-behind-relative-one).

Don't ask me why, but the last answer there seems to fix the problem (though you'll need jQuery or the like):

http://jsfiddle.net/Xmznn/1/

Comment: the js method can fix this issue, but I just wanna know if there is a way to do it with css only?

Comment: this way to travelsal all of the matched elements and set its `z-index` attribute with a lower value than its previous element. I don't think its a good way to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Give all `div`s with class `rela` an `z-index`, the first with the hightes till the one on the bottom with the lowest value.

```
<div class="rela" style="z-index: 40;"><div class="abs"></div></div>
<div class="rela" style="z-index: 30;"><div class="abs"></div></div>
<div class="rela" style="z-index: 20;"><div class="abs"></div></div>
<div class="rela" style="z-index: 10;"><div class="abs"></div></div>
```

Also see this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/8QyxT/).

Comment: This is almost same as the "js solution", to set a lower value to the element than its previous one. But I don't think its a good way.

Comment: That's not nice, but I fear that it is the only option.

Comment: I also feel a little pessimistic that maybe there is no other way to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

see the changes, it is working in IE 7

```
 .rela{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background:#EEE;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.abs{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:#333;
    margin:80px 0 0 20px;
    z-index:0;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Remove the `position:relative;` from `.rela` will cause the `.abs` lost its reference point, so actually, all of the `.abs` elements are located at the same position.

Comment: did you test this code, because it is working properly for me in IE7, 8 and 9, Firefox, chrome, safari and Opera?

Comment: I know, it looks that it works, but actullay, all of these four `.abs` are located at the same place, they are covered by each other.

Comment: till now you didn't test the code. .abs is not in the same place, margin:80px 0 0 20px will take care to position one after the other.

Comment: oh, sorry, it's my fault.. it looks beautiful. But you know, if the height of the gray part is changeable. this way will be not suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Try  adding

```
z-index : 0;
```

To div.rela

Comment: Or you could just make your site say "why IE?" whenever someone uses IE on it! Does it work on IE8+? I gave up trying with IE7, let alone 6!

Comment: yes, it works well on IE8+ and other browses. I have gave up IE 6&7 for my site. But it's a req of my company's project.

Answer (score 0):

know issue and well documented out there.
check - http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

that might help you out.

Comment: uh, I found this site just now, its condition doesn't match mine, all of these elements need to fix this issue, if so, it equals to don't add a higher z-index to the parent elements.

Comment: no matter what, it comes down to the same bug. if you look at scessor's response, that will in fact work.

Comment: yes, the "js solution" is the same thinking as scessor's solution. I think maybe this is the only way to fix this issue. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

There's a helpful [resource](http://alex.leonard.ie/2013/01/27/ie-bug-text-ignores-z-index-of-higher-elements/) to address this issue.

Long story short, if your absolutely placed div (.abs) is empty, IE doesn't like to place it in front of other elements regardless of z-index. You can use a 1x1 transparent gif to overcome this, eg. by setting a style like the following on the div:

```
 .abs {
   background: transparent url('/images/clear.gif') repeat 0 0;
 }
```

I've found this to help. It's great as there's very little additional styling needed and you don't have to explicitly manage z-indices.