# IE7 z-index with an unordered list

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, z-index

The following example is a very simplified version of my top navigation.

http://jsfiddle.net/AEqxT/

If you look in most browsers, you should see two green list items next to eachother, with a blue box or 'badge' sitting on top, bridging the gap between the two. In IE7 however, the blue box always falls below the second li. I've tried all manner of fixes to this. Setting a higher z-index to the parent ul didn't change anything, and if I use `position: relative;` on the 'badge', it loses its width and height.

Is there an obvious fix to this that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably struggle with your badge in with the LI, take it out of the list and you should be ok, with a bit of messing with position:

http://jsfiddle.net/AEqxT/2/

If you absolutely have to have it in with the LI, then you'll probably have to have some JS to make this work

Comment: I liked your idea about removing the badge from the li, but I couldn't position it absolutely as you suggested, as the badges are generated programatically, so their position is never consistant. So instead, I created another li with the badge inbetween the two main list items, as so - http://jsfiddle.net/A2Pe3/1/ It's not entirely semantic, but it seems to do the job. Thanks for the inspiration!

Answer (score 0):

This is a [reported IE7 bug](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2006/01/Explorer_z_index_bug.html).

You could fix it with the JS solution posted to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524987/ie7-absolute-element-appearing-behind-relative-one), or you could manually set different z-indexes to all `<li>` element, ordered from high to low values:

http://jsfiddle.net/AEqxT/3/